# iOS UIImagePickerController, set frame

Tags: ios, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to accomplish the following result:

Set the frame of my UIImagePickerController to, lets say 200 x 200,

Set my frame at the bottom-right corner (just like Facetime/Skype does)

and show the front/rear (doesn't matter) camera stream.

Here's my code, for some reason, setFrame is not working!

```
self.picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
self.picker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
self.picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
self.picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
self.picker.navigationBarHidden = YES;
self.picker.view.frame = CGRectMake(600, 400, 200, 200); // NOT WORKING !!!
self.picker.toolbarHidden = YES;
self.picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = NO;
self.picker.delegate = delegate;

[self presentViewController:self.picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

1. I've looked at similar SO topics but they all talk about how to

   set a view on top of the UIImagePickerController, not my problem at all.
2. I've tried adding self.picker to a custom UIView sized 200 x 200 but still

   no success.

What am i doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: check what values do you pass here - is 600,400 within screen bounds?

Comment: This may be because Apple recommends that you present the camera interface only full-screen.

Comment: @NiravBhatt, thanks but i wrote 600,400 as an example, if you want, make it 0,0.

Comment: @Puneet, please dude, if Skype, Viber and Apple (FaceTime) did it, so can we.

Comment: This isn't really how that class is supposed to be used. You should be using the foundation classes like `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`.

Comment: Are you sure you want to change the picker's frame and not it's overlayview's?

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the `cameraViewTransform` property of `UIImagePicker` to adjust its camera frame. This property accept any `CGAffineTransform` you made (e.g. scaling, rotating, inverting, translating, etc).

For example, if you want to move the camera view down by 50 points and scale the camera view 1.2x its original size, this is how you'll do it:

```
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0f, 50.0f);
    transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1.2f, 1.2f);
    imagePicker.cameraViewTransform = transform;
```

Swift 5:

```
var transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0.0, y: 50.0)
transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2.0, y: 2.0)
imagePicker.cameraViewTransform = transform
```

Answer (score 2):

From UIViewController reference [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController%3aanimated%3acompletion%3a)

**presentViewController:animated:completion:**

**Discussion**

**On iPhone and iPod touch, the presented view is always full screen**

If you want to embed image picker, you should manually add its view to one of your other views.

like this

```
[self.view addSubview:self.imagePickerController.view];
```

I experimented with the code from my last post, and commented out the final scale transform ((the one which makes it full size) and I ended up with a lovely miniature camera imagePicker floating in the middle of my screen, so it definitely does work! The exact code I used, including the zoom/fade-in transition, is -

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePickerController.delegate = self;
imagePickerController.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage, nil];
imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
imagePickerController.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;

UIView *controllerView = imagePickerController.view;
controllerView.alpha = 0.0;
controllerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5);

[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] addSubview:controllerView];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
          delay:0.0
        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
     animations:^{
         controllerView.alpha = 1.0;
     }
     completion:nil
];
[imagePickerController release];
```