# How to open camera in small region of view in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, avcapturesession, ios-camera

I have to open camera in my app in small region of screen ,but not getting how to implement it,because camera opens on full screen genreally.
[image]

The camera should be open in uiimage view region,Plz guide me how to achieve this.Thanks.

Comment: Have u got solution for your problem ? I have to open camera on UIView whose size is 320*273. I tried AVCam also but didn't get successed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at [AVCam](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html) sample project provided by Apple. It has all the features you need for your task. Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

I experimented with the code from my last post, and commented out the final scale transform ((the one which makes it full size) and I ended up with a lovely miniature camera imagePicker floating in the middle of my screen, so it definitely does work! The exact code I used, including the zoom/fade-in transition, is -

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

imagePickerController.delegate = self;
imagePickerController.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage, nil];
imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
imagePickerController.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;

UIView *controllerView = imagePickerController.view;

controllerView.alpha = 0.0;
controllerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5);

[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] addSubview:controllerView];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
              delay:0.0
            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
         animations:^{
             controllerView.alpha = 1.0;
         }
         completion:nil
];

[imagePickerController release];
```

you can go through my answer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19152478/2695503)